# HTML5 Datepicker has no ISODate() wrapper when stored to MongoDB with MEAN Stack. How to query?

Tags: html, mongodb, datepicker, mean-stack, isodate

The field "planned_depart_date" uses an html date input is used to select a date. That is saved as an ISO Date but does not have the ISODate() wrapper around it when saved to MongoDB. As a result, my queries on "planned_depart_date" return nothing. However, when I query the same thing but on "created_at" (which does have the ISODate() wrapper), it works.

```
<input type="date" ng-model='trip.planned_depart_date'>
```

So what's going on? Is there a way to force HTML5 to have the ISODate() wrapper? If not, how can I query my db so that I can get those dates?

I want to query for trips with a planned_depart_date equal to or later than today.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps converting `$scope.trip.planned_depart_date.toISOString();` before saving it would help

Answer (score 0):

ISODate() constructor returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper.Convert the coulmn to date.Then you can query as
`db.trips.find({"planned_depart_date":{$gte:ISODate("2016-01-15T20:57:31.745Z")}})`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not return any results from the database. Is the planned_depart_date even an ISODate? It looks like one but has no wrapper. When I try just `Date()` it also returns nothing.

Comment: Yes.The column planned_depart_date is string and not date.It should have an ISODate() wrapper to query based on date.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, I discovered my silly mistake. Notice in the screenshot that all the `planned_depart_date` are all strings... My Mongoose model was accepting `planned_depart_date` as a string and not a date.